# API $expand and &count

Tags: dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is it possible to use `$expand` but instead of returning a collection of objects, just return the count of objects?

For example, get an account **and** a count of its annotations in a single WebApi call

I've tried a few things.

- Obvious attempt: `accounts(6CDEEB72-2AC8-E711-A825-000D3AE0A7F8)?$select=name&$expand=Account_Annotation($count=true)` returns all fields of all Annotations but doesn't count anything.
- Next I tried `accounts(6CDEEB72-2AC8-E711-A825-000D3AE0A7F8)?$select=name&$expand=Account_Annotation($select=annotationid&$count=true)`  returns an error: "*Found an unbalanced bracket expression*". I think this is related to the <kbd>&</kbd> symbol in the `$expand`
- I found a non-crm blog that said this could be resolved with a <kbd>;</kbd> but when I tried `accounts(6CDEEB72-2AC8-E711-A825-000D3AE0A7F8)?$select=name&$expand=Account_Annotation($select=annotationid;$count=true)` it doesn't give an error, but the `$count` instruction seems to be ignored
- A crazy attempt of `accounts(6CDEEB72-2AC8-E711-A825-000D3AE0A7F8)?$select=name&$count=Account_Annotation($select=annotationid)` returns a "*not a valid count*" error

I'm guessing that this is not a valid combination, but I thought I would post here in case someone else has achieved this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, but I'm not sure it's what you are looking for exactly, it only works if I put the count before expand:

```
api/data/v9.0/cmnt_salesexample?
$select=endcustomeraccountid&$count=true&$expand=endcustomerid($select=accountid)
```

output:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://xyz",
"@odata.count": 5000,
"value": [
 {
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"3560581422\"",
  "endcustomerid": "54321"
},
{
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"3510396844\"",
  "endcustomerid": "12345"  
},
...
```