# Count records returned from $extend in Dynamics 365 Web API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Basically, I have something like this:

```
https://company.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=accountid,accountnumber,name&$expand=crm_productbuyer($select=name)
```

I'd like to be able to just get a count of the number of records returned in the `$expand` instead of deserializing it in C# and doing a count on it. Just one lest thing to iterate over.

This didn't work for my case:

[API $expand and &count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747018/api-expand-and-count)

**EDIT:**

There are a number of things here that indicate this isn't doable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api#retrieve-related-entities-for-an-entity-by-expanding-navigation-properties

> You can’t use the /$ref or /$count path segments to return only the URI for the related entity or a count of the number of related entities.

---

> This is a subset of the system query options described in the “11.2.4.2.1 Expand Options” section of OData Version 4.0 Part 1: Protocol Plus Errata 02. The options $skip, $count, $search, $expand and $levels aren’t supported for the Web API.

Will mark this an answer unless someone else chimes in to demonstrate otherwise.

Comment: I tried asking the same thing a while ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747018/api-expand-and-count). Sadly I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't sound like it is doable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api#retrieve-related-entities-for-an-entity-by-expanding-navigation-properties

> You can’t use the /$ref or /$count path segments to return only the URI for the related entity or a count of the number of related entities.

---

> This is a subset of the system query options described in the “11.2.4.2.1 Expand Options” section of OData Version 4.0 Part 1: Protocol Plus Errata 02. The options $skip, $count, $search, $expand and $levels aren’t supported for the Web API.